# if i use http for part of my website and https for another part does this open up any security issues

Tags: node.js, http, https

I have a node.js app.

I have it configured to redirect everything to https from http.

but i was thinking if the extra work to make the normal pages visible on http and the logged in pages only visible via https, would be worth the effort.

does having both in my app expose any security holes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes multiple, including:

1. Cookies are shared between the two sites unless you remember to include the "secure"  attribute each time you set a cookie.
2. You are vulnerable to MITM attacks (e.g. replacing a "login" link on http to either keep you on http or redirect you to another site instead).
3. Resources need to be loaded over https on the secure site or you will get mixed security warnings. It's easy to miss this when running mixed sites.
4. Users will not know whether pages should be secure or not.
5. Can forget to renew cert and/or see cert errors but this should be more obvious if whole site is https.
6. Cannot use advanced security features like HSTS.

And that's just off the top of my head.

Go https everywhere and redirect all http traffic to https. Unless you've a good reason not to.

There are other benefits too (user confidence, looks more professional, small SEO boast, Google sees this as two sites, easier management of sites, Chrome will soon block access to some features like location tracking on http, cannot upgrade to HTTP/2 until you implement https... etc.).